# Condensing Row Data into a View

Tags: sql-server

I have data in my `PeopleInfo` table where there are some people that have multiple records that I am trying to combine together into one record for a view.

All people data is the almost the same except for the `PlanId` and `PlanName`. So:

```
| FirstName | LastName |    SSN    | PlanId | PlanName |   Status  |  Price1 | Price2 |
|-----------|----------|-----------|--------|----------|-----------|---------|--------|
|   John    |    Doe   | 123456789 |    1   |  Plan A  |  Primary  |  9.00   |  NULL  |
|-----------|----------|-----------|--------|----------|-----------|---------|--------|
|   John    |    Doe   | 123456789 |    2   |  Plan B  | Secondary |  NULL   |  5.00  |
```

I would like to only to have one `John Doe` record in my view that looked like this:

```
| FirstName | LastName |    SSN    | PlanId | PlanName |   Status  |  Price1 | Price2 |
|-----------|----------|-----------|--------|----------|-----------|---------|--------|
|   John    |    Doe   | 123456789 |    1   |  Plan A  |  Primary  |  9.00   |  5.00  |
```

Where the `Primary` status determines which PlanId and PlanName to show. Can anyone help me with this query?

Comment: Why is this down voted? I feel like it is a legitimate question...

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table ( FNAME varchar(10),  LNAME varchar(10),    SSN varchar(10),    PLANID INT,PLANNAME varchar(10),stat varchar(10),Price1 decimal(18,2),Price2 decimal(18,2))
insert into @t (FNAME,LNAME,SSN,PLANID,PLANNAME,stat,Price1,Price2)values ('john','doe','12345',1,'PlanA','primary',9.00,NULL),('john','doe','12345',1,'PlanB','secondary',Null,8.00)
select 
FNAME,
LNAME,
SSN,
MAX(PLANID)PLANID,
MIN(PLANNAME)PLANNAME,
MIN(stat)stat,
MIN(Price1)Price1,
MIN(Price2)Price2 from @t
GROUP BY FNAME,LNAME,SSN
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I was wondering if you may explain it better. How does the `Max` and `Min` functions apply in this situation.

Comment: every thing is same except price and Plans are different so you want to eliminate Null price values to get into single record so max and min can give us exact result @scapegoat17

Comment: The only thing that troubles me here is that i am also determining which `PlanId` and `PlanName` since they are different and i want to show a specific one based off of the `Status` field of both records.

Answer (score 0):

(I can't yet add a comment, so have an answer.)

> The only thing that troubles me here is that i am also determining which PlanId and PlanName since they are different and i want to show a specific one based off of the Status field of both records.

Then you don't even need `GROUP`ing. It would be much simpler. Just `SELECT WHERE 'Primary' = PlanName`. Assuming that (A) there will always be this PlanName for each user, and (B) You are happy to ignore all others.

P.S. If you will only be using Primary and Secondary PlanNames, you might want to change the column to a `bit` named something like isPrimaryPlan where 1 indicates true and 0 false. However, if you might bring in *e.g.* Bronze and Consolation Prize Plans later, then you'll need to retain a more variable datatype. Perhaps store the plans in a separate table and have an `int FOREIGN KEY` to it... I could go on!

Comment: Thank you for the response, but then this does not combine the Price data for an Person...

Comment: Ah I see. Unfortunately you can't really have both targeted selection of a single row for one column + aggregates for the others. I'll see whether I can think of anything else. Maybe a MIN or MAX of PlanName would get you what you want, depending on how those parse strings - I'm rusty in this area.

Comment: I see... thanks anyway. Also, just a note, the fee's would need to be `SUM` of the two.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm back after having a sleep, which has improved my brain slightly,

First, let the record reflect that I don't like the database design here. The People and Plans should be separate tables, linked by foreign keys - via a 3rd table, e.g. PeoplePlans. That takes me to another point: the people here have no `primary key` (at least not that you have specified). So when writing the below, I had to pick the SSN, assuming that will always be present and `unique`.

Anyway, something like this *should* work, with the caveat that I'm not going to replicate the database structure to test it.

```
select
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    SSN,
    PlanId,
    PlanName,
    Status,
    _ca._sum_Price1,
    _ca._sum_Price2
from
    PeopleInfo as _Primary
    cross apply (
        select
            sum(Price1) as _sum_Price1,
            sum(Price2) as _sum_Price2
        from
            PeopleInfo
        where
            _Primary.SSN = SSN
    ) as _ca
where
    'Primary' = Status;
```

This `SELECT`s all People with Primary status in order to get you those rows. It then `CROSS APPLY`s their Primary and any other rows and takes the summed Prices.

Hopefully this makes sense. If not, you'll have to do some reading about `CROSS APPLY`, in addition to about good relational database design. ;-)